# Is there a pure Java framework for gesture recognition?

Tags: java, gesture-recognition

Is there any specific Java gesture recognition out there? [iGesture](http://www.igesture.org/) is very old. [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is based on C/C++, I used some Java wrapper like [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/), but I cannot find any resource and documentation for it. Is there any pure Java framework for gesture recognition? Please suggest if you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after several days confusion and working on different solutions, and using C# wrappers or Java wrappers and different .Net frameworks and java frameworks. find out its better to install openCV and use it in visual studio 2008 and program it with C++... believe me thats the easiest way, these links at below were so helpful for using openCV libraries into Visual Studio 2008:
http://7evin.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/opencv-visual-studio-2008-in-windows-vista/
http://uowteaminvincible.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/getting-started-with-opencv-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2008-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Do more recent Visual Studio versions have any problems with OpenCV that Visual Studio 9 doesn't have?

Comment: Your solution doesn't really answer your question.  Not helpful for others that need to use Java.